# PL/SQL Script to add value in the next row

Tags: oracle, plsql

i have  a Select which contains a Object and a specific track information.
example:

```
OBJECT  ANK      ABF    LAUFNR
661             19:09   3
661             19:18   6
661     19:20   19:22   7
661     19:23           8
```

now i need a PL/SQL which takes the value ABF and add's the Value to the next row in field ANK
example:

```
OBJECT  ANK      ABF    LAUFNR
661             19:09   3
661     19:09   19:18   6
661     19:18   19:22   7
661     19:23           8
```

the PL/SQL should work with the SQL.

also i have another SQL without a Number

what I meant above: i have 2 SQL (both with rownum) by the 2nd i have rownum +1 and i matched both to come to the result. my idea was to have a PL/SQL script .... because i have another selects without any number (example- laufnr in the select above) example without a number

```
OBJECT  from       To
661     H   H1     Sns
661                Jb
661                Bri H1
661     Bri H1     Bri
661                Rdf H1
661     Rdf H1     Rdf
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need  a stored procedure?

Comment: now i have a solution via Rownum, but i need the sql a second time.
and i think a PL/SQL would be the best

Comment: What do you need with "need the SQL a second time"? I also don't understand what "*the PL/SQL should work with the SQL*" is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select object,
    nvl(ank, lag(abf) over (partition by object order by laufnr) as ank,
    abf, laufnr
from your_table
;
```

This will select the data for you. If you need to update the `your_table` with the data, it will be a slightly different query.

Comment: now i get 
OBJECT ANK ABF LAUFNR
661 19:18 19:09 3
661 19:22 19:18 6
661 19:20 19:22 7
661 19:27 19:23 8
661 19:27 19:27 9
but if a make
nvl(ank, lead(abf) over (partition by OBJECT order by laufnr desc)) as ank
IT WORKS ... MANY THANKS!

Comment: @user1856981: Ah, yes, sorry, I'm an idiot. Answer corrected.

Comment: you are not an .... it works perfect !! thanks !!
but could you also make a PL/SQL?

Comment: @user1856981: PL/SQL, that's the trouble a_horse_with_no_name is speaking about in comments above. None of us seems understand what you mean by that, what is your target *state of things*.

Comment: what I meant above: i have 2 SQL (both with rownum) by the 2nd i have rownum +1 and i matched both to come to the result. my idea was to have a PL/SQL script .... because i have another selects without any number (example- laufnr in the select above)

example without a number
OBJECT from to
661 H   H1 Sns
661  Jb
661  Bri H1
661 Bri H1 Bri
661  Rdf H1
661 Rdf H1

Comment: @user1856981, for readability reasons, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26904410/edit) your question with this additional info instead of putting the additional info into comments.

Comment: HI all, now all is clear from my side!!  i had a thinking error.. with lead and lag i can do all what i need ... many thanks